# Is it possible to specify a SQL Server schema name in a Rails ActiveRecord migration?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The current convention where I work is to use SQL Server schemas like namespaces (e.g. Company.Employees, Company.Branches, etc.)  Is it possible to get an ActiveRecord migration to use anything other than the default "dbo" schema in SQL Server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your migration, supply table names with schema prefix to create_table and drop_table calls.

```
create_table("Company.Employees") do |t|
  t.column :name, :string, :limit => 60
  # Other fields here
end
```

In the model, override the default table name using `set_table_name`.

```
class Employees < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "Company.Employees"
end
```

**On the other hand**

If all the tables used in your rails application belong to the same schema, then you can assign that schema as the default schema for the DB user specified in the database.yml file.

Comment: Based on my findings, this works in Rails 3.x, but not Rails 2.x (I'm testing in 2.3.2). Does anyone have experience to the contrary? Or another solution?